# Calling a function within foreach loop in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm trying to use a foreach loop but if I try to fit a Gumbel distribution within the loop I get the error

"Error in { : task 1 failed - "The  dgumbel  function must be defined""

I have read many posts about functions and foreach loops and they all seem to suggest putting ".export = functionname" into the foreach line. I did this and don't understand why it is still not running. If I exclude the Gumbel fistdist line and fit only normal distributions, it all works fine. 
If I use a normal for loop, the fitdist of a Gumbel distribution works fine,too.

```
# create data that will be used to fit a distribution
cum_prec <- matrix (nrow= 80, ncol=10)
x = c(1:6, 8:10)
for ( i in x){
  cum_prec[,i] <- rnorm(80,400, 50)}
cum_prec[,7] <- rGumbel(80,400, 50)


# package fitdistrplus does not work for the gumbel distribution. Therefore, the gumbel distribution has to be added manually.

dgumbel <- function(x,a,b) {1/b*exp((a-x)/b)*exp(-exp((a-x)/b))}
pgumbel <- function(q,a,b) {exp(-exp((a-q)/b))}
qgumbel <- function(p,a,b) {a-b*log(-log(p))}


library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)




clim <- foreach (n=1:10,  .export=c("dgumbel", "pgumbel","qgumbel"), .combine= cbind,  .packages= "fitdistrplus") %dopar%


{
    rep=10000


normal <- matrix(nrow=rep, ncol=10)
x = c(1:6, 8:10)
for ( i in x){
  Normal<-fitdist(cum_prec[,i],"norm")
  normal[,i] <- rnorm(rep,Normal$estimate[1], Normal$estimate[2])
}



Gumbel<-fitdist(cum_prec[,7],"gumbel", start=list(a=0,b=1),optim.method="Nelder-Mead")
normal[,7] <- rGumbel(rep,Gumbel$estimate[1], Gumbel$estimate[2])


SU <- vector("numeric", rep)
for (i in 1:rep){
  su = (quantile(normal[,1], probs=runif(1,0,1))+ quantile(normal[,2], probs=runif(1,0,1)) + quantile(normal[,3], probs=runif(1,0,1)) 
        + quantile(normal[,4], probs=runif(1,0,1))+ quantile(normal[,5], probs=runif(1,0,1))+  quantile(normal[,6], probs=runif(1,0,1))
        + quantile(normal[,7], probs=runif(1,0,1))+  quantile(normal[,8], probs=runif(1,0,1))+  quantile(normal[,9], probs=runif(1,0,1))
        + quantile(normal[,10], probs=runif(1,0,1)))/10

  SU[i] <- su 
}

} 

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: You need to add `clusterExport(cl, c("dgumbel", "pgumbel", "qgumbel", "rgumbel"))` statement before `registerDoParallel(cl)`. I simply defined `rgumbel <- rGumbel`. Also your `foreach` doesn't return anything, probably `return(SU)` should be added.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AndreyKolyadin! The clusterExport() solved the problem with the gumbel function. You are right that the foreach doesn't return anything which is strange. I thought by starting with "clim <- " and using ".combine='cbind'" the SU vectors would be cbinded to clim. I added return(SU) before I closed the foreach loop but it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Edit: It works now with the 'return(SU)'. I changed 'n=1:10' to 'i=1:10'. I don't know why this makes a difference but it works.